# Can I pull items in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to create a following structure:

```
|                                         |
| [item][item][item]          [item][item]|
|                                         |
```

There are 5 items inside. They are all vertically aligned to the middle. 3 first elements are pulled to the left and 2 last elements are pulled to the right.

I know I can use floats for it, but it has several drawbacks, including troublesome vertical aligning.

I decided to use flexbox, which turns out to be a lot more convenient and flexible. Plus, it's more responsive-friendly.

Now my question is, can I distribute my elements like this in flexbox? Ideally, each of those 5 elements would be flexbox item. But how can I tell flexbox to pull those 3 to the left and those 2 to the right? I think adding empty element to fill space is not the best idea.

Is this doable or do I need to do it like this?

```
|                                         |
| [      item      ]          [   item   ]|
|                                         |
```

Where each item would contain needed elements inside, or perhaps even be separate flexboxes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `display: flex` along with `margin-left: auto` for the 4<sup>th</sup> child element

```
<main>
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
</main>
```

Css

```
main {
  display: flex; 
}

div {
   width: 12%;
   margin: 0 10px;
   border: 1px red solid;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKvMOw

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could stick w/ Flexbox Layout and let the flex prop do all the magic.  Personally, I don't like setting margins (other than `margin:0;`) in a flex box layout, it can throw off the layout and also generate unwanted scroll bars.

```
<div class="rowNoWrap">
  <div class="flexyChild">[  item  ]</div>
  <div class="flexyChild">[  item  ]</div>
  <div class="flexyChild">[  item  ]</div>
  <div class="flexyChild">[  item  ]</div>
  <div class="flexyChild">[  item  ]</div>
</div>

.rowNoWrap {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -o-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.flexyChild {
    flex: 1;
}
.flexyChild:nth-child(4) {
    flex: 5;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Gives you this layout:
[image]

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Serk0413/u6556q1s/)

Comment: I don't like this approach. What if you add items to flexbox? `5` is no longer valid. I think there are cases where `flex-grow` is useful, but not too many and for sure not this one.

Comment: Not sure exactly where you mean to add these items but 5 is always valid, even if you add items to this div.  Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean it affects other items widths.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add another way to implement flexbox. No margins, paddings, borders, or special selectors. I added 2 extra elements in order to divide the main flex container (`.main`) with 2 nested flex containers (`.sub.left` and `.sub.right`).

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Consolas;
  list-style: none;
}
body {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
.main {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 2px dashed yellow;
}
.node {
  outline: 4px solid red;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}
.sub {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 3px dotted lime;
}
.left {
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.right {
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.msg {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.ylw {
  color: yellow;
}
.grn {
  color: lime;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main">
  <ul class="sub left">
    <li class="node">[ item ]</li>
    <li class="node">[ item ]</li>
    <li class="node">[ item ]</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sub right">
    <li class="node">[ item ]</li>
    <li class="node">[ item ]</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p class="msg"><span class="ylw">Yellow</span> = .main
  <br/><span class="grn">Green</span> = .sub
  <br/><span class="red">Red</span> = .node
```

Comment: Run your code and shrink the window. Total waste of space.

Comment: @RoboRobok wtf do you mean? It's responsive, it shrinks as the viewport shrinks as expected. The colored lines are there for demonstration so you can see where the elements are. I used `outline` which is like borders but they do not affect dimensions like `borders` do. Are you a 12 year old?

Comment: The items should take as much space as they need and with your solution they can't. With small screen width, items start to wrap, even though there's a ton of space in this empty element. Understood now?

Comment: I understand that wasn't the question. > Now my question is, can I distribute my elements like this in flexbox? Ideally, each of those 5 elements would be flexbox item. But how can I tell flexbox to pull those 3 to the left and those 2 to the right? I think adding empty element to fill space is not the best idea.